# p:panelGrid inside p:panelGrid, how to remove borders in an outer p:panelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have an outer `<p:panelGrid>` and I use it for layout (I know regarding the element `<p:layout>` but couldn't achieve same results with it as with `<p:panelGrid>`). Inside this `<p:panelGrid>` I have various elements `<p:dataTable>`, another `<p:panelGrid>`, etc...

I need to remove borders in an outer `<p:panelGrid>` but everything I've done affect borders of the internal elements as well. I tried `nth-child(n)`, I tried catch specific borders with `#form\\:outer-panel-grid tr, #form\\:outer-panel-grid td`, nothing. Every time internal borders disappearing as well.

Maybe somebody have a working solution for this issue? Thank you.

UPDATE: This is **jsf** code below, and [link](http://jsfiddle.net/anatoly314/1ebqxvu9/) to generated **HTML** code on **jsfiddle**.

```
     <style>
        #form\:main-panel td{
            border: none !important;
        }

        #form\:main-panel tr{
            border: none !important;
        }
    </style>



      <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="growl" />
        <p:panelGrid id="main-panel">
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    outer table column 1
                            <p:panelGrid>
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column>
                                        inner table column 1
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column>
                                        inner table column 2
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:row>
                            </p:panelGrid>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    outer table column 2

                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: cannot help without the code, upload it to jsfiddle.net so that someone can help

Comment: Do you want to remove borders around an outermost `<p:panelGrid>` only? i.e. borders around other `<p:panelGrid>`s inside the outermost `<p:panelGrid>` should not be affected - they should remain as they are? @Rusty : Adding a JSFiddle is difficult because HTML is rendered by server side XHTML tags.

Comment: @Tiny, yes exactly. **Rusty, Tiny**, I've added to jsfiddle code which was generated by **JSF**, under the hood it's same HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply style rules to jsf components use styleClass attribute :

```
 <p:panelGrid id="main-panel" styleClass="outerpanelgrid">
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                outer table column 1
                        <p:panelGrid styleClass="innerpanelgrid">
                            <p:row>
                                <p:column>
                                    inner table column 1
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column>
                                    inner table column 2
                                </p:column>
                            </p:row>
                        </p:panelGrid>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                outer table column 2

            </p:column>
        </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Try using following style rule :-

```
.outerpanelgrid>tbody>tr{
    border: none !important;
}
.outerpanelgrid>tbody>tr>td{
    border: none !important;
}
```

OR another option is you can set border for inner panelgrid.

```
 .outerpanelgrid tbody tr, .outerpanelgrid tbody td{  
    border: none;
 }
.innerpanelgrid tbody tr, .innerpanelgrid tbody td{
    border: 1px solid red ;
}
```