# Remove all border on all panelgrids not on datatables

Tags: css, primefaces, border, panelgrid

I need to hide all borders of all panelGrids using primefaces. The following code remove the borders on all panelGrids and dataTables too (primefaces 5+):

```
.ui-panelgrid tr, .ui-panelgrid td {
    border: none;
}
```

I need this effect only in panelGrids. After that and I need to know how to show the borders only in some panelGrids

Comment: May help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059960/ppanelgrid-inside-ppanelgrid-how-to-remove-borders-in-an-outer-ppanelgrid/29062798#29062798

Comment: Learn basic css, learn how to use developer tools to test css, Learn how to use styleClass to create selectors etc. This technically is not even a PrimeFaces issue, just plain css/html

Comment: Thanks @BhavinPanchani but I need to do it in all panelGrids of my application and then I need to show borders only one panelGrid.

Comment: @Kukeltje I know how to work with those technologies but I don't know how to do what I asked

Comment: @JohnB: Sorry, but I tend to disagree. Let me guess... The datatables are inside the panelgrid right

Comment: Hint: try something like: `.ui-panelgrid > * > tr, .ui-panelgrid > * > tr > td.ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}`

Comment: To remove the borders for all panelGrid use this :  .ui-panelgrid tr, .ui-panelgrid td {
    border: none;
}  and for those panelGrid you want border :  apply styleClass and use : appliedStyleClass tr, appliedStyleClass td{ border : 1px;}

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje your comment works for me. Could you put it as answer please? I will use the developer tool to see the your solution affect only panelGrids but dataTables

Comment: Thanks @BhavinPanchani but your solution doesn't work for me

Comment: @BhavinPanchani: to complex if you want to be able to use themes... What border do you assign then? And it still removes borders for descending datatables

Comment: @JohnB: So you now know a little more about css ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS selectors are to 'broad'. They influence *all* `<tr>` and `<td>` tags that are descendants of a `.ui-panelgrid`, including all that are in a table that is *in* a panelgrid cell as descendants of the table that makes the datatable. So you have to make your selectors more specific (read about css specificity on mozdev) and have them **only target a certain level** .

Use e.g.

```
.ui-panelgrid > * > tr, .ui-panelgrid > * > tr > td.ui-panelgrid-cell {
     border: none;
}
```

This only targets `<tr>`'s that are a grandchild of a `.ui-panelgrid` and its direct `<td>` children.

If you don't want this applied to *all* panelgrids, You'll have to use the styleClass referred to in a comment above by @BhavinPanchani. But instead of explicitly adding borders by using a class, you prevent the css above to be applied.

```
.ui-panelgrid:not(.keepBorder) > * > tr, .ui-panelgrid:not(.keepBorder) > * > tr > td.ui-panelgrid-cell {
     border: none;
}
```

Just add the `keepBorder` class to the panelGrids that you want to keep the border. I did not test this last thing, but with a little testing you;

**See also**

- [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

Comment: How can I put the borders in one panelGrid when I have applied this solution?

Comment: I'm almost tempted to refer to _"@... I know how to work with those technologies but I don't know how to do what I asked "_, but I won't... (hmmm just did)... I'll update the answer

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje. I know them but I'm not an expert :)

Comment: :-) ok… but to me (but I might be to outspoken) this is part of css 'basics' and by reading one good introduction, you'll at least know what is all possible. Applying it might fail sometimes then, but SO comes to the rescue then.